# How to make the apply() function faster?

Tags: r, apply

I have two matrices. I want to use the columns of the first one to filter the second one and then find the sum of the filtered set. I used the following code and it works perfectly fine.

```
apply(firstMat,2,function(x) sum(secondMat[x,x]))
```

However, the dataset is large and I want to find an alternative approach that makes the process faster.

Here is the reproducible example in a small scale:

```
firstMat<-matrix(c(T,F,T,F,F,T,T,F,F,F),nrow=5,ncol=2)
secondMat<-matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)
```

I will be really thankful if you can help me on that.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and desired output.

Comment: I've added that to the question. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your BLAS is faster than the explicit loop:

```
diag( t(firstMat) %*% secondMat %*% firstMat )
```

Comment: You are right. Even this one works better:  rowSums(t(firstMat)%*% secondMat*t(firstMat))

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `apply` function in parallel on multiple clusters

```
firstMat<-matrix(c(T,F,T,F,F,T,T,F,F,F),nrow=5,ncol=2)
secondMat<-matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)

# create custers
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK") # creates 2 clusters 
# can use detectCores() from package parallel to check number of cores in your machine
registerDoSNOW(cl)
clusterExport(cl,list("secondMat")) # need to export secndMAT to each cluster since will be used in cluster

# Option 1: Using parApply from package `parallel`
library(parallel)
parApply(cl,firstMat,2,function(x) sum(secondMat[x,x]))

# Option 2: Using aaply from package `plyr`
library(plyr)    
aaply(firstMat,2,function(x) sum(secondMat[x,x]),.parallel=T)

stopCluster(cl)
```

With the small reproducible example, it doesn't show any speed improvements, but I would expect both options to be faster than `apply` for large matrices

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I also expected to get better performance with parallel analysis. But the result became worse.